# Convex NMF implementation

Tags: r, nmf

I need Convex NMF to explore some dat asets in R. I can not find any Convex NMF implementation in packages: `NMF`, `NMFgpu`. Any idea how to search for it?

```
??cNMF
??convexNMF
>No results found
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Questions about recommendations for packages are off-topic for SO, but if I interpret this as **how do I find ... ?**, then the `sos` package is a good solution.  It does a full-text search of all CRAN packages.

```
library("sos")
findFn("convex NMF")
```

Comment: Thank you, i changed the question accordingly.